# Can anyone tell me what kind of tree this is?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, nut-trees

My family and I ate lunch at the park today (North Carolina) and found this fruit tree. **The tree is on the smaller side and has large oval leaves. The fruit is roughly two thumbs thick, is pale orange when ripe, has a pit and grows in bunches**. My first instinct is that this is an older breed of Peach tree (I learned within the last year they used to be much smaller than the store variety) but my family disagrees since they lack the typical fuzz. Does anyone have a better idea of what this could be?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a persimmon to me. I live in NY and have no direct experience with persimmons, but it seems like a close match judging from images online.

Comment: Persimmons are fairly common in the south. Once the fruit gets yellow, people who like them say it is improved by freezing. When I ate them directly from the tree ,I was not impressed. Deer love them straight from the tree.